# How do we know the big bang expanded space and there wasn't a pre-existing volume for the universe to expand into?

Tags: big-bang-theory

Whenever we hear an explanation about the big bang, it is always phrased in such a way that it was an explosion which used some kind of pressure to expanded the universe out.

I wonder, however, would it be possible that our universe bubble started as a point that wrapped around the singularity and contained it.  Then, for some reason, this bubble started to expand, which caused the energy in the singularity to fill the newly created empty space.

Could it be that this bubble, which is now our universe, is still expanding, and the universe is still trying to fill the space, which is why we see dark energy?

Could we even know, or would either way look exactly the same to us?

Comment: This would imply the initial universe had a finite radius. I am sure that could be a falsifiable proposition.

Comment: "Explosion" is not a particularly good word to use.  It's the source of much popular confusion, and is reinforced by all of the cool explosion effects they use when talking about the Big Bang on television.  "Everywhere big rip" is perhaps more accurate.

Comment: You'll likely find this old article (1997) by the father of inflationary theory, Alan Guth, to be very revealing: WAS COSMIC INFLATION THE 'BANG' OF THE BIG BANG? http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Guth/Guth_contents.html It's not *unspeakably* technical.

Comment: Prof. Guth has an excellent set of lectures on youtube that are well worth watching (and IIRC may have hints to an answer to this question somewhere) search for 8.286 Early Universe.

Comment: maybe the answer is Zeroth law of thermodynamics, maybe if we had a temperature constant, unlike to 0, this would show that we are in a closed place like a bubble